# Getting "Void value not ignored as it ought to be" when trying to assign a function pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, struct

So, I have a structure with a function pointer inside (called tFunc). I want to create an instance of that struct and assign "tFunc" to a specific function. In this case the function I want to assign is "fromAtoB(event evt)". But I get "Void value not ignored as it ought to be". I don't get why.

### StateMachine.h:

```
struct event{
int id;
QByteArray data;
};

typedef void (*transitionFuntionPtr)(event);
struct row{
event evt;
transitionFuntionPtr tFunc;
string output;
};


class StateMachine : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:

enum States{StateA, StateB, StateC};

explicit StateMachine(QObject *parent = 0);
int currentState;
struct event lastEvt;
multimap <int, row> transitionTable;

void EventHandler(struct event evt);
list<row> getEvtTable(struct event evt);
void setup();

void fromAtoB(struct event evt);
};
```

How I assign the function pointer inside StateMachine.cpp:

```
StateMachine::StateMachine(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

struct row r;
struct event evt;
evt.data = "";
evt.id = 0;

r.evt = evt;
r.output = "GOT EVENT ID: " + evt.id;
r.tFunc = StateMachine::fromAtoB(evt); // ASSIGNMENT OF THE FUNCTION POINTER
}
```

error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     r.tFunc = StateMachine::fromAtoB(evt);

Thanks :)

### EDIT:

So it was pointed out to me that I should change the assignment to

```
   r.tFunc=StateMachine::fromAtoB;
```

but now I get this error: cannot convert ‘StateMachine::fromAtoB’ from type ‘void (StateMachine::)(event)’ to type ‘transitionFuntionPtr {aka void (*)(event)}’
     r.tFunc=StateMachine::fromAtoB;

### EDIT #2:

I made the function "fromAtoB(event evt)" to static and now it compiles, but won't that make me unable to create objects from StateMachine?

Comment: Regarding your edit#2: No, but it _will_ prevent you from accessing object specific state in `fromAtoB`. This may or may not be a problem depending on what that function is supposed to do.

Comment: yes, you're right. The problem is that I want to be able to change the variable "currentState" inside that function... Which is a problem.

Comment: Are you free to use C++11 features?

Comment: Yes I guess so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here.

First, as pointed out by the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42810043/577603) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42810052/577603) answers, you actually invoke the function when trying to assign it.

The other problem, pointed out by your edit, is that you are trying to bind a member function to a plain C function pointer. This does not work, you would need to use C++ member function pointers for this. The reason for this is that a call to a member function works different from a call to a free (or static) function: Since a member function depends on the object state, the compiler has to implicitly pass a pointer to the object on which you want to invoke the member function as a hidden parameter. Problem with C++ member function pointers is that they are horrible. Lucky for you, C++11 addressed this problem.

Starting with C++11 there is [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), which should be your preferred solution when you need to pass function-y things around (you have to `#include <functional>` for this). `std::function` is a template that gets parameterized with the signature of the function that you want to assign to it:

```
std::function<void(event)> func = &StateMachine::fromAtoB;  // won't compile!
```

But, wait, that won't work either. Remember what we said earlier, about the compiler implicitly passing a pointer to the object on a member function call? Well, here we have to make that explicit to make things work:

```
std::function<void(StateMachine*, event)> func = &StateMachine::fromAtoB;

StateMachine m;
Event ev;
func(&m, ev);
```

You can hide the fact that the function call depends on a `StateMachine` object by wrapping the call in a lambda:

```
StateMachine m;
std::function<void(event)> func = [&m](event e) { m.fromAtoB(e); };

Event ev;
func(ev);
```

Note that this will explode horribly if you let `m` die before `func`, as the lambda keeps a (non-owning) pointer to `m` which will be left dangling when `m` is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
r.tFunc=StateMachine::fromAtoB(evt);
```

means "call `fromAtoB()`, passing it `evt`, and assign the return value to `r.tFunc`".

You meant:

```
r.tFunc = StateMachine::fromAtoB;
```

Not sure that will build either, though, since that looks like a reference to a static method and `fromAtoB()` is an instance method. Sharing pointers to instance methods with non-class code can be hairy, since the `this` pointer needs to be managed.

The usual solution is (was?) to provide a static method in the class that acts as a trampoline into the instance method (but perhaps there's a better solution now, it was years since I wrote C++).

Comment: The usual solution these days would be to use `std::function` instead of plain function pointers. Of course you still need to take care of passing the `this`-pointer along.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the syntax, in your code

```
 r.tFunc=StateMachine::fromAtoB(evt);
```

is an attempt to put the return value of the function call, not the function pointer. So the compiler is right to complain, as the function return type is `void`.

Remove the function call operator, like

```
 r.tFunc = StateMachine::fromAtoB;
```

Comment: So I changed it and now I get this error: cannot convert ‘StateMachine::fromAtoB’ from type ‘void (StateMachine::)(event)’ to type ‘transitionFuntionPtr {aka void (*)(event)}’
     r.tFunc=StateMachine::fromAtoB;

Comment: LuísAbreu:  I am not much into C++, maybe @unwind can help you out in resolving that.